# Trying hard to solve error 1064

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, common-table-expression

I have tried hard but not getting the solutin regading sp below.. plz help !!

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AccountLedgerViewUnderBank()

begin


WITH GroupInMainGroup (accountGroupId,HierarchyLevel) AS
(
select accountGroupId,
1 as HierarchyLevel
from tbl_AccountGroup where accountGroupId='9'
UNION ALL
select e.accountGroupId,
G.HierarchyLevel + 1 AS HierarchyLevel
from tbl_AccountGroup as e,GroupInMainGroup G
where e.groupUnder=G.accountGroupId

)
SELECT
ledgerId AS 'Account Ledger Id',
acccountLedgerName AS 'Account Ledger Name'
FROM tbl_AccountLedger

where accountGroupId IN (select accountGroupId from GroupInMainGroup
)
end ; //
```

The error showing

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Group
InMainGroup (accountGroupId,HierarchyLevel) AS
(
select accountGroupId,
1 a' at line 6
```

Comment: MySQL does not support common table expressions. You need to upgrade to a DBMS that allows them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use a CTE, which is not supported with MySQL (at time of writing).

Subqueries are supported with most versions of MySQL, so you may be able to rewrite it as something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AccountLedgerViewUnderBank()

begin

SELECT      ledgerId AS 'Account Ledger Id',
            acccountLedgerName AS 'Account Ledger Name'
FROM        tbl_AccountLedger

where       accountGroupId 
    IN     (select accountGroupId 
            from tbl_AccountGroup where accountGroupId='9'
            UNION ALL
            select e.accountGroupId
            from tbl_AccountGroup as e,GroupInMainGroup G
            where e.groupUnder=G.accountGroupId)
end ; //
```

Comment: thanks.. but you have missed ; before end on line 16 . +5 to u